# Changing text after a <br> with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `span` tag like this and stored in the variable "foo"

```
<span class="right margin">
    <a href="./?p=filmdetail&amp;fid=644&amp;fileid=722&amp;t=میراث چینی 3D">سی ئی 1500</a>
    <br>
    Nicole Kidman
</span>
```

Using jQuery OR javascript, how can I change the "Nicole Kidman" clause with something I want? innerHTML changes everything in the `<span>`

Edit: I edited the text with this code `foo[0].lastChild.nodeValue="something else";` but is there another way doing that using only jQuery?

Comment: You want this to happen `onClick` of the `<a href>` ?

Comment: @GauravBhor: Yes, I have to change the site html so by clicking a button some elements change. On of them is changing that clause I said.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend you add another `span` tag around `Nicole Kidman`.

```
<span class="right margin">
    <a href="./?p=filmdetail&amp;fid=644&amp;fileid=722&amp;t=میراث چینی 3D">سی ئی 1500</a>
    <br>
    <span>Nicole Kidman</span>
</span>
```

and change the text like this:

```
$(".right").find("span").text("something you want");
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I'm not allowed to do that.

Comment: By the way, how can I wrap the `Nicole Kidman` with `<span>`?

Comment: @alireza Actually in jquery, you have to select the node first to wrap it with another tag, like this : `$('#someId').wrap('<span></span>');`, but you cannot select `Nicole kidman` in this case (otherwise you need not ask this question).

Answer (score 1):

Here the `foo` is not a jQuery object:

```
foo.lastChild.textContent='something you want'
```

---

So the `foo` is a jQuery object, but you still need to access the dom element directly:

```
foo.contents().eq(-1).textContent='something you want'
```

Comment: your code throws this: "TypeError: Cannot set property 'textContent' of undefined"
(I'm using chrome console.)

Comment: I changed your code to `foo.find(':last-child')` but this returns the `</br> and by `textContent` I can't change the "nicole kidman" clause.

Answer (score 1):

1. `<span>` is an inline element. We avoid using `<br/>` in them.
2. It is also advisable to use another tag to encapsulate your 'Nicole Kidman' text.(Like another `<span>`)

I'm not aware of your entire HTML structure so I'm going with what you have posted. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/gauravbhor/TQWyL/2/) is a fiddle example for how it can be done.